# Post page displaying sub page without URL change

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, slug

I am working on a website on WordPress for a company and I am running into the following issue. This is the structure:

Section:

```
fruits
```

Categories (sub-sections):

```
red, yellow, blue, orange
```

Items (sub-sub-sections):

```
apples, oranges, lemons, blueberries
```

`Fruits` is based on the `Posts` section of the site (it has the little pushpin beside it). The category plays into the URL for that page, so when an item is selected it would look something like:

```
food.com/fruits/red/apples/
```

The category page has it's own page with some visual navigation and a blurb about that category. When the fruits are selected and you navigate to one of those categories however, the page shows the content of the fruit instead of the category page that was built itself.

For ex, the URL looks like:

```
food.com/fruits/red/
```

but it is showing the page

```
food.com/fruits/red/apples/
```

without changing the URL.

The only way I have remedied this so far is by NOT selecting a category, however then I run into the issue where the URL for that fruit page looks like this:

```
food.com/fruits/colour/apples/
```

I haven't been able to find any information on this subject so far, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the following image you can see that the next step displays the wrong page, however the permalink at the second page is the same in both cases.

[visual of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8WwA.jpg)

### Edit:

*archive-fruits.blade.php*

```
@include('page')
```

*page.blade.php*

```
@php $iterator = 0 @endphp
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  @while(have_posts()) @php the_post() @endphp
    @if ($flexible_content)
      @foreach ($flexible_content as $block)
        @if ($block->block_type == 'markets_slider')
          @include('partials.markets-slider')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'static_content')
          @include('partials.static-content')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'expandable_content')
          @include('partials.expandable-content')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'image_+_text_listings')
          @include('partials.image-plus-text-listings')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'farmers_markets_list')
          @include('partials.farmers-markets-list')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'fruits_list')
          @include('partials.fruits-list')
        @elseif ($block->block_type == 'tabbed_content')
          @include('partials.tabbed-content')
        @endif
      @endforeach
    @endif

  @endwhile
@endsection
```

layouts: *app.blade.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<html {!! get_language_attributes() !!}>
  @include('partials.head')
  <body @php body_class() @endphp>
    @php do_action('get_header') @endphp
    @include('partials.header')
    <div class="wrap container" role="document">
      <div class="content">
        <main class="main">
          @yield('content')
        </main>
        @if (App\display_sidebar())
          <aside class="sidebar">
            @include('partials.sidebar')
          </aside>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
    @php do_action('get_footer') @endphp
    @include('partials.footer')
    @php wp_footer() @endphp
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get how you are working. Sorry, that I can't comment but I don't have enough reputation yet. This "fruit" is a custom-post-type or is the "post" function itself? What does it mean "without changing the URL"?

You can alter the permalinks of the posts in the settings of Wordpress, following `Settings>Permalink`, and add the category in the URL, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rKW5.png).

Comment: Sorry, I know this is confusing! Fruit is a custom-post-type. I will add an image to hopefully help with the explanation.

Comment: I saw the photo. For what I can understand you want that the first button (red), that is a category of a custom post type, to open the archive of the category. You say that what actually happens is that the first button (red) directly opens the post it contains.
Or maybe it opens the category archive that is directly filled with the category content. Maybe the first button doesn't represents the category archive at all...
We need many more details, such as how you created the custom post type and what is your code.

Comment: Ok I read again the thread and saw the photo. It's all more clear now.
It seems that the category archive page is working in some strange way. We need the code of the template of such archive: maybe it is intended to directly show the content of the posts instead of a list of them.
Such template should be named archive-fruits.php somewhere in the folders, but if you created the CPT, it may be that Wordpress is using the [default archive](https://imgur.com/a/P3d1j73) of the Theme as a fallback.

Comment: Yes thank you! I did not know how to explain this problem but that's exactly it - my archives page is not displaying properly for some reason. The archive page itself only says `@include('page')` and in `page` there are many `if (some_layout_type) include (some_partial)`. The rest goes down a rabbit hole and is far too much information to post on here, but thank you so much this points me in the right direction.

Comment: Let's start adding at least the code of the archive page and of the "page" page. It could be that you need to create a new archive page or copy it from the default files of Wordpress. Edit your question.
I still haven't understood if the archive page you are referring to is the default *archive.php* or a custom archive page like *archive-fruites.php*.

Comment: I have added 3 of the files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you created the CPT, but it uses the default page template as an archive template. This means that you won't have a list of posts inside the category archive, just the content.
You have to create an archive template inside that *archive-fruits.blade.php*, substituting that one line which is already there.

You can take a look at how an archive template is made in the file *archive.php* of any Wordpress Theme, but this is a Custom Post Type, so there may be differences (like the fact that is named *archive-fruits*). Nothing that a [quick search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+archive+template+for+custom+post+type) couldn't solve. I suggest you start reading [the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/) and then some guides.